# Can sscanf be used to match wildcards?

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings, stdio

For instance consider an array of C strings, all digits

```
..."12334", "21335", "24335"...
```

and I want to know how many of these strings matches this wildcard mask

```
**33* (where * = any digit 0-9)
```

Could I use `sscanf(str, mask, ...)` to accomplish this? The format `"%1d%1d%[3]%[3]%1d"` seems to match more than I want (when 33 isn't there) and `"%1d%1d33%1d"` seems to behave weirdly, matching some but not all matching entries.

The context in my code:

```
if (sscanf(array[i], mask, &a1, &a2, &a3) == 3)
```

3 being the number of wildcard digits matched.

Comment: Can you show your full code, including the check of the return value?  A program with `int main()` using `argv[1]` as the first argument to `sscanf()` would be perfect.

Comment: @John Zwinck I added the line used to check. `mask` is the format I described, `a1,a2,a3` are 32 bit `int`s. I'm really just asking, if `sscanf` is capable of doing what I described, and what the format should be

Comment: @jefferson You've got a few options. 1) Abuse strchr to make sure the first and second occurrences in the string are at your desired places. 2) Hand-make integers so that you can match every possible combination.

Comment: Are you really set on using `sscanf` for this?  It seems like a bit of a sledge-hammer, when no string-to-integer conversion is necessary.

Comment: A regular expression match seems more appropriate for this than `sscanf`.

Comment: @paddy no I am not set on using `sscanf`, I was wondering if it was possibly without the use of a regex library. `scanf` doesn't support regex matching does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format `"%1d%1d33%1d"` should be correct, assuming your inputs are all numbers.  But you haven't told us *what* specific inputs it's failing on.  You should consider that the strings `"1 2334"` and `"  1\n\n233 \t   4"` would actually match because `%d` will eat whitespace until it finds an integer.

Beware that if you were to use `"%2d33%1d"` this would be even worse, because a 2-character integer can be a single digit with a negative.

In case it's not already apparent, using `sscanf` for this type of matching is not appropriate.  You are better off using a regular expressions library, which excel at this kind of thing.

However, by far the simplest approach, if you just want something quick that works, is to use short-circuit evaluation along with `isdigit`.  You don't even need to check the string length:

```
int matches( const char * s )
{
    return s
        && isdigit(s[0])
        && isdigit(s[1])
        && '3' ==  s[2]
        && '3' ==  s[3]
        && isdigit(s[4]);
}
```

Comment: There's an additional problem that if there are double quotes in the string to be matched, or commas or spaces, then the integer-related format string won't skip the quotes; it will simply reject them as not matching the format.  I agree that `sscanf()` is not the right tool for the job.